# Existence of a non-zero function

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space. Is there a $\mu$-measurable function $f$ which satisfies the following properties?

0) $f \geq 0$

1) $\int_X f d\mu < \infty$

2) The function is not identically zero

3) $\inf \{f(x) | x \in F \} = 0$, $\forall F \in \mathcal{F}_\mu, F \neq \phi$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no measurable function satisfying (0), (2), and (3).  If $f$ is a nonnegative measurable function that is not identically zero, then for each $\lambda>0$, the set $F_\lambda=\{x\in X:f(x)>\lambda\}$ is measurable, and since $\displaystyle{\{x\in X:f(x)>0\}=\cup_{\lambda>0} F_\lambda}$, not all $F_\lambda$s are empty.  Let $\lambda_0>0$ be such that $F_{\lambda_0}\neq \emptyset$.  Then $\inf\{f(x):x\in F_{\lambda_0}\}\geq\lambda_0>0$.

Comment: Thanks, nice answer. These were the three important conditions for me. I can do away with (1).